GNOME mouse pointer misaligned/offset between visble cursor location and actual clicking location
I've little idea how to describe this issue, so would welcome edit suggestions.
Sometimes the mouse clicking location and the mouse pointer location are offset or misaligned in my installation of GNOME with Ubuntu 22.04 and X11. I see the effect in Firefox and in Nautilus, and currently the only solution I have is to reboot. I would welcome some understanding of the cause of the issue and perhaps a way to address it.
Here is a video illustrating some of what I'm seeing:
https://imgchest.com/p/dl7pqnnw8yo
In the video you can see a Firefox window open. I right-click on the web page to open a context menu, and then the misalignment of the mouse visible pointer and the mouse actual clicking location seems to start. As the visible pointer moves about on the right of the window, the actual clicking location seems to reset to the top-left corner of the window and is seen through the hover reactions of the different Firefox buttons at the top-left.

If you're seeing this in both Nautilus and Firefox it could be a bug anywhere in the "GUI stack" those depend on, but first I would try and downgrade GTK to a previous version to see if that fixes it (unless downgrading would break stuff).

Just to pinpoint the problem: What happens when you switch from X11 to Wayland (Ubuntus default)?

@kanehekili Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately since I don't know what is triggering the issue, I don't know how to reproduce it. All I know right now is that it happens once every few days. (I can't switch for Wayland for days at a time as it is missing features on which my workflow depends.)

This is exactly similar issue I was reporting. Caused by driver for graphic tablet or touchpad. Try to remove driver with sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
For Ubuntu 22.04, a switch from libinput to Synaptics can be accomplished with commands like the following:
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput


Thanks for your comment. Your suggestion looks to have resolved the issue (I'll know with more reliability after a few days. I edited your solution so that people won't remove libinput without Synaptics being available, which could cause input issues if they're unfamiliar.

worked for me too on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
